# Applying CSS animation using ng-class not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I've some basic experience with AngularJS but I'm an absolute beginner in CCS animations.
Said that, I'm trying to cobble these stuff together:

- In the CSS I defined 2 different "blink animation" classes: `.blink-anim-slow` and `.blink-anim-fast` referring the same `@keyframes` defintion with different durations
- With 3 radio buttons you can choose the animation for a `<div>`: *none* / *slow blinking* / *fast blinking*
- Simple `<div>` with `ng-class` attribute to apply the different animations

Everything works as expected in Chrome and Firefox.
However, in **IE11** I get this special behavior:

**Switching between slow and fast blinking works not directly, I have to go over "none" first and then I can apply "slow" or "fast".**

Here's a Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/16aQRENmVj3wdpv9BQiE?p=preview

Now I'm a little bit confused where my mistake is... CSS or Angular related?

I read about media queries and IE, but I'm not using this.
I'm not sure if I need to use ngAnimate for that... but probably not for such a simple use case.

Many thanks for guiding me in the right direction or for an updated plunkr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way to solve this, but I don't know if this is a workaround for an IE bug or if it has to be done really like this.

**Fact is:** When I use ***two separate `@keyframes` definitions*** (one for slow blinking and one for fast), everything works in all 3 tested browsers.

Here's the Plunker with the updated CSS: http://plnkr.co/edit/PQ2iiusXGdLwcCrJfF1T?p=preview

I'm still not the CSS guru, but for me it makes no sense to have the same `@keyframes` defined twice just with different names. However, the real difference comes in place later when referencing the `@keyframes` with different animation-durations.

Please comment if you know more facts about this. Thanks!